# Can Shortcodes be used in a Static WordPress Homepage?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, static-pages

I have a Static page set as the home page of my wordpress website. It has a custom shortcode to show a woocommerce catalog based on my own meta query.

When I add valid products, it does not show up immediately or even after a while. However, if I publish the static page, then it shows up magically, thus leading to my question.

What are my alternatives, if I want to show my shortcode on a static home page?

I think this is my problem and nothing else, because I tried disabling all plugins and clearing the cache, but still it did not show the latest added products.

Comment: Yep, actually I tried switching across multiple themes.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the template of your theme adding the do_shortcode() function where you want the shortcode to be displayed, for example:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: The problem is that static page refuses to change. I delete the entire content and just put "Hello Word", from the page editor and still the page does not change. However, if I click "Preview Changes" from within the Editor, I can see the "Hello World", not when I click on "Update" from the Page Editor